# CTE Query performance difference with similar codes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, query-performance

I am seeking an analysis for query performance based on standard/best practices. Any re-writes or inputs to optimize my code are welcome.

I am using a SQL-server based web based tool to query a database where I only have Execute permissions. No SSMS environment to analyze Query plans. I am trying to figure out the *reason behind performance differences* between two sets of similar code. I've removed some additional fields from the `SELECT`statement which are common to both and would've impacted performance equally. Also, I'm `CONVERTING` casted dates back to `datetime` because of an external limitation.

Case 1: Repetitive and detailed `CASE` statements with calculations. No extra CTE's hence 1 less `JOIN`

Case 2: Shortened Aliases using additional `DateCTE` resulting in extra JOIN

Currently, Case 2 is taking 4-5 times longer to execute than Case 1

**Code for Set 1:**

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT
    C.client_id AS [Client ID]
    ,CAST(CV.date1 AS DATE) AS SDate
    ,VT.label AS Service
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN VT.label='A' THEN CAST(CV.date1 AS DATE) END) OVER (PARTITION BY C.client_id) AS [FirstAssist Date]
    ,CI.billing_ord AS Ord

FROM C
INNER JOIN CV
    ON C.client_id=CV.client_id
LEFT JOIN VT
    ON VT.visittype_id=CV.visittype_id
LEFT JOIN CI
    ON CI.client_id=C.client_id
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    CTE.[Client ID]
    ,CONVERT(datetime,COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN CTE.Service LIKE '%med%' AND CTE.SDate >= CTE.FirstAssistDate THEN CTE.SDate END) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.[Client ID])
                                                                    ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,CTE.FirstAssistDate, MIN(CASE WHEN CTE.Service LIKE '%med%' THEN CTE.SDate END) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.[Client ID])) >=-5
                                                                     THEN MIN(CASE WHEN CTE.Service LIKE '%med%' THEN CTE.SDate END) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.[Client ID]) END)) 
     AS [Start Date]

   ,COALESCE(DATEDIFF(day, CTE.[FirstAssist Date], MIN(CASE WHEN CTE.Service LIKE '%med%eval%' AND CTE.SDate >= CTE.[FirstAssist Date] THEN CTE.SDate END) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.[Client ID]))
                                        ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, CTE.[FirstAssist Date], MIN(CASE WHEN CTE.Service LIKE '%med%eval%' THEN CTE.SDate END) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.[Client ID])) >= -5
                                         THEN ABS(DATEDIFF(day, CTE.[FirstAssist Date], MIN(CASE WHEN CTE.Service LIKE '%med%eval%' THEN CTE.SDate END) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.[Client ID]))) END) 
    AS [Days to Treat]

FROM CTE
INNER JOIN (SELECT CTE.[Client ID], MIN(CTE.Ord) AS MinOrd FROM CTE GROUP BY CTE.[Client ID]) InsCTE ON CTE.[Client ID]=InsCTE.[Client ID] AND CTE.[Ord]=InsCTE.MinOrd
WHERE 1=1
    AND CTE.[Client ID] NOT IN (SELECT [Client ID] FROM CTE WHERE Service LIKE 'B')
    AND CTE.SDate BETWEEN '20150701' AND '20170301'
```

**Code for Set 2:**

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT
    C.client_id AS [Client ID]
    ,CAST(CV.date1 AS DATE) AS SDate
    ,VT.label AS Service
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN VT.label='A' THEN CAST(CV.date1 AS DATE) END) OVER (PARTITION BY C.client_id) AS [FirstAssist Date]
    ,CI.billing_ord AS Ord

FROM C
INNER JOIN CV
    ON C.client_id=CV.client_id
LEFT JOIN VT
    ON VT.visittype_id=CV.visittype_id
LEFT JOIN CI
    ON CI.client_id=C.client_id
)
,DateCTE AS
(SELECT
     [Client ID] 
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN CTE.Service LIKE '%med%eval%' THEN CTE.SDate END) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.[Client ID]) AS MedEvalDate
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN CTE.Service LIKE '%med%eval%' AND CTE.SDate >= CTE.FirstAssistDate THEN CTE.SDate END) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.[Client ID]) AS FirstMedEvalDate
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN CTE.Service LIKE '%med%' THEN CTE.SDate END) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.[Client ID]) AS MedSvcDate
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN CTE.Service LIKE '%med%' AND CTE.SDate >= CTE.FirstAssistDate THEN CTE.SDate END) OVER (PARTITION BY CTE.[Client ID]) AS FirstMedSvcDate
  FROM CTE
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    CTE.[Client ID]
    ,CONVERT(datetime,COALESCE(DateCTE.FirstMedSvcDate,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,CTE.FirstAssistDate, DateCTE.MedSvcDate) >=-5 THEN DateCTE.MedSvcDate END)) AS [Start Date]
    ,COALESCE(DATEDIFF(day, CTE.FirstAssistDate, DateCTE.FirstMedEvalDate),CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, CTE.FirstAssistDate, DateCTE.MedEvalDate) >= -5
        THEN ABS(DATEDIFF(day, CTE.FirstAssistDate, DateCTE.MedEvalDate))END) 
    AS [Days to Treat]

FROM CTE
INNER JOIN (SELECT CTE.[Client ID], MIN(CTE.Ord) AS MinOrd FROM CTE GROUP BY CTE.[Client ID]) InsCTE ON CTE.[Client ID]=InsCTE.[Client ID] AND CTE.[Ord]=InsCTE.MinOrd
INNER JOIN DateCTE ON CTE.[Client ID]=DateCTE.[Client ID]
WHERE 1=1
    AND CTE.[Client ID] NOT IN (SELECT [Client ID] FROM CTE WHERE Service LIKE 'B')
    AND CTE.SDate BETWEEN '20150701' AND '20170301'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, anything anyone tells you is going to be a guess, because there isn't enough information. For example, it could be that your `DateCTE` is throwing the estimated amount of rows off (because how is SQL going to know how many rows match wildcards like that when you can't index that sort of thing?) and because of that SQL is choosing a very suboptimal plan (for your needs). But as mentioned, anything said about why it's happening is going to be a guess. Best practice is to look at the query plan but you can't do that so I'm not sure how anyone can help, really.

Comment: @ZLK I understand. It's like picking a needle out of a haystack without a plan but it was worth a shot in case something really pops out in the code. I'll try investigating that DateCTE Inner Join more. If there's a better way or method besides CTE's that is generally less intensive, I'll be interested to know about that too. Thank you.

Comment: When you run into performance problems with CTEs, lose the CTEs and populate intermediate data in temporary tables. Nine times out of ten your problems disappear.